# Linq/Entity Framework query is not recognizing all my range variables

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I want everything in FileLists as long as there is a corresponding record in Tools. I have 0..1 to many relationships between Machine, PrintTypes and MaterialTypes. I have a many to one between FileLists and Tools. I want all the records from FileLists if there is a match in Tools. The values in Machine, PrintTypes and MaterialTypes are optional. If they exist in that tables I want that as well, if they do not I just want null displayed. I think this is a right outer join.

My query looks like this:

```
            var query = 
                from tool in context.Tools
                join file in context.FileLists on tool.ToolID equals file.ToolID
                into machine from rt in machine.DefaultIfEmpty()
                //join print in context.PrintTypes on file.PrintTypeID equals print.PrintTypeID
                //join material in context.MaterialTypes on file.MaterialTypeID equals material.MaterialTypeID

                where file.IsFirstPartRecord == false
                orderby file.FileListID ascending
                select new {
                    ToolNumber = tool.ToolNumber,
                    Description = tool.Description,
                    Date = file.Date,
                    Time = file.Time,
                    FileListID = file.FileListID,
                    MachineName = machine.Name,
                    //PrintType = print.Name,
                };
```

When I add the line:

```
            into machine from rt in machine.DefaultIfEmpty()
```

All the file.XXX have errors. The error is:

> The name 'file' does not exist in the current context

What is wrong with my syntax?

Comment: you break the joining with this line. Therefore a new query begins and file isn’t scoped after the line.

Comment: TL;DR: You should select `rt.XXX`.

Comment: And short advice: it might become slightly simpler to understand if you switch to method syntax instead of query syntax. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/query-syntax-and-method-syntax-in-linq)

Comment: You're probably gonna get another error on the `machine.Name` line - that's because `machine` is a collection of grouped `FileList` items. Idk if you really need this because you're selecting from this collection (line `from rt in machine.DefaultIfEmpty()`), so you might as well use `rt.XXX`.

Comment: OK. So this worked but it is complete voodoo to me. Somehow adding "into mac from rt in mac.DefaultIfEmpty()" and then I can get any fields from tables that have relationships with FileLists by using "rt.TableName.FieldName". What is "into mac from rt in mac.DefaultIfEmpty()" actually doing?

Comment: You can avoid all these confusing manual joins by defining and using navigation properties.